# Why does part of my PHP form appear in plain text on the page?

Tags: php, html, forms

My form, for some reason, won't parse all of the php script.About the first half of it is hidden from the user's view (where it belongs),but the code after the `<a href>` tag all displays in plain text on the page. here is the full code (I know the default values for email ,subject, etc are wrong but that's after the href tag anyway and I see no need to add that information until I have working code)

```
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
{ 
?> 
<form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
Your name:<br> 
<input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
Your email:<br> 
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
Your message:<br> 
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
</form> 
<?php 
}  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
$name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
else{         
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
    $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
    mail("youremail@yoursite.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
    echo "Email sent!"; 
    } 
}   
?>
```

This is what the code that shows up as plain text looks like:

```
`the form again."; } else{ $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
$subject="Message sent using your contact form"; mail("youremail@yoursite.com", 
$subject, $message, $from); echo "Email sent!"; } } ?>`
```

Here is the resulting page: http://kgcrittersitters.com/simple_form.htm

I actually do have a full form with all the field IDs filled out in the PHP script (http://kgcrittersitters.com/hire_phptest.htm), but I wanted to get what
appears to be the biggest error with the code taken care of before I fixed
it on a larger page.

Comment: Have a look at the source code for the page; none of the PHP is being executed. I'd guess that it's because you have it in a .htm file, rather than a .php one.

Comment: OK, I'll try putting it in a php file and adding action="../form_email.php" to the form

Comment: Oh my god...It WORKED!!! http://kgcrittersitters.com/hire_php.php I've been going at this for two (insert swear of choice) days, and most of my previous questions are related to this form. Of course I still haven't filled out the email address for it to actually send yet (it's still youremail@yoursite.com and all the other fields are ""), but it executes now!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute php code inside a .html file. Try change the extension to .php

Comment: @Hulu8004 not really, its a pretty badly asked question, but still, this is the solution.